# Memory issues (stomping?) within C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, kdtree

I'm trying to build a 3d tree structure `PhotonMap` which I can add `Node`s to.

`Node` :

```
class Node
{
    public:
        Node(Photon);
        Node();
        virtual ~Node();
        Node *left = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
        Photon self;
    protected:
    private:
};
```

With the constructor being what you'd imagine

`PhotonMap` :

```
class PhotonMap
{
    public:
        PhotonMap();
        virtual ~PhotonMap();
        void insert(Node);
        Node *root = nullptr;
        vector<Node> nodes;
        bool first = true;
    protected:
    private:
        Node * insertMain(Node *node, Node *newNode, int depth);
};
```

```
void PhotonMap::insert(Node node) {
    nodes.push_back(node);

    if (first) {
        root = &nodes.back();
        first = false;
    }
    else {
        insertMain(root, &nodes.back(), 0);
    }
}
```

```
Node * PhotonMap::insertMain(Node *node, Node *newNode, int depth) {
    cout << endl;
    if (node == nullptr) {
            node = newNode;
        return newNode;
    }

    int dimNo = depth % 3;
    switch (dimNo) {
    case 0:

        if (newNode -> self.position.x >= node -> self.position.x) {
            cout << "R : " << (node -> right == nullptr);
            node -> right = insertMain(node -> right, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        else {
                cout << "L : " << (node -> left == nullptr);
            node -> left = insertMain(node -> left, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (newNode -> self.position.y >= node -> self.position.y) {
                cout << "R : " << (node -> right == nullptr);
            node -> right = insertMain(node -> right, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        else {

                cout << "L : " << (node -> left == nullptr);
            node -> left = insertMain(node -> left, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (newNode -> self.position.z >= node -> self.position.z) {
                cout << "R : " << (node -> right == nullptr);
            node -> right = insertMain(node -> right, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        else {

                cout << "L : " << (node -> left == nullptr);
            node -> left = insertMain(node -> left, newNode, ++depth);
        }
        break;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Additionally there's `Photon` which holds 3 vectors: `energy`, `direction` and `position`.

Clearly, any `Node` should have both `left` and `right` a `nullptr` until it's set within the `insert` function. When I run the following:

```
PhotonMap pm;
Photon p;
p.position = Vertex(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
Photon p2;
p2.position = Vertex(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Node node(p);
Node node2(p2);
pm.insert(node);
pm.insert(node2);
```

I would expect that the initial `node` will be stored locally in the vector `nodes` and set the `root` pointer to the address of `node` in `nodes`, after which `node2` should:

Have its photon's x position value checked against `node`'s x position

See that its x value is lower

Print "L : 1" (since `node`'s `left` and `right` should both be `nullptr`).

However, I get

```
L : 0
L : 0
R : 0
L : 0
```

So it appears as if neither of `node`'s `left` or `right` are `nullptr` despite not being changed?! Since neither are `nullptr`, the program follows the trail of garbage pointers until it crashes. I was getting `std::bad_alloc` earlier on but now I'm not. I have a feeling that there may be some memory stomping issue where the pointers `left` and `right` are getting overwritten by something. It doesn't appear as if the entirety of the initial node is being overwritten as it's still possible to print its position.

Thanks for any and all help :)

Comment: When you add items to a `vector` you may trigger a reallocation of the storage used to get more space, invalidating all of the pointers you have stored. The left and right pointers point to memory that USED to be owned by the `vector`. See [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) for more information.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! Is there any way to work around this? Scalable storage is an absolute must for this tree (I can't precalculate the size) but I also need the random access speed. Vector was looking perfect for this (though apparently not, now)

Comment: If you never remove items from or re-order the `vector` you can turn left and right into `size_t` and store the index in the `vector` rather than the pointers.

Comment: Amazing idea! Thank you!